# {line-breaking} vs. {newline}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I just saw that we have both [line-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-breaking) and [newline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newline). I always used [line-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-breaking) so far. Is there are reason why we need [newline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newline)?

I would vote for making [newline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newline) a synonym for [line-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-breaking).

---

Are there are objections against merging these two tags?

Comment: There's even a question that has _both!_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No objection. (This is a classic case of concept tag vs. command name tag.)

Comment: I made newline a synonym for line-breaking now.